# Win32 assembly conditional jumps

Tags: assembly, x86, opcode

With respect to the following opcode reference: http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html

I'm trying to understand a little more around conditional jumps. You'll see in the above-referenced link that the opcode for "Jump short if zero/equal (ZF=0)" is **74**. Therefore, if we (in a debugger) binary insert the bytes **74 04** and the ZF flag is set to 0, we will see a short forward jump of **4** bytes:

```
0207FF9F        74 04        JE SHORT 0207FFA5
```

No problems there.

Later on in the same reference, there is a similar conditional short jump referenced using opcode **85**, however if you pop that code in with a similar byte length for the conditional jump, you get the following:

```
0207FFA5        850441        TEST DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+EAX*2],EAX
```

[image: Attempted conditional jump]

I'm clearly not understanding something here, is someone able to explain? Are conditional short jumps based on flag values limited to opcodes **70** through **7F**?

Comment: @mazegen made a typo in the reference mentioned above: the condition of *Jump if zero/equal* is actually **ZF=1** rather then ZF=0, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd `85` you found is in the 2-byte opcodes table, where every entry is prefixed with `0F`.

The "near" (rel32) [version of JZ/JE is `0F 85`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html).  (Oops, that HTML extract truncates the list of encodings, only getting to a few of the `0F ..` rel32 versions.  Or actually has broken non-table formatting for the rest.  See Intel's PDF original.

Those opcode tables are not instruction set reference manuals.  They're handy if you just need a quick reference, though.  If you ever get confused, look up the instruction in the full manual (links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

Comment: Thank you Peter - tested this and the 2-byte opcode does seem to work in terms of initiating a conditional jump. The only other question I have is how to I specify the byte jump length? Entering say, 04, after the opcode doesn't initiate a 4-byte jump - it actually references an invalid memory address (in this case JE 434640A8).

I see from Intel's original opcode doc you mentioned that the jump conditions referenced is *0F 87 cd* - I will also look into *cd* vs *cb* which is present in many other jumps.

Thx!

Comment: @SirSaucealot: `0F 85` is the 32-bit displacement version of the instruction.  That's why there are two: for short jumps (8-bit displacement), and the added-in-386 32-bit displacement version ("near jumps", as opposed to far jumps that also change CS).  Read the instruction set reference manual entry: it explains the encoding.  Or assemble the instruction in an assembler to see what you get.

Comment: I see *cd* references byte value after the opcode, I'll get there with more reading and testing! :)

Comment: @SirSaucealot: yeah, that means `dword` (instead of `byte`), as explained in the intro section of the insn set ref manual.  The text Description section of the manual entry I linked makes it clear that there are rel8, rel16 (for 16-bit mode), and rel32 (for 32 and 64-bit mode) jumps.  Each encoding has a rel32 or rel8 in the "instruction" column, one to the right of the encoding.  Of course, it's often easiest to just put mnemonics into an assembler and see what comes out, instead of always going the other way around with a disassembler.